# Verilog bit indexing

Tags: fpga, verilog, system-verilog

A signal is defined as :

```
logic [width_x-1:0] x;
```

I want to assign x a value where the second bit from the top is '1' and all other bits are '0'.
For example, if width_x is 4 then I want x to be "0100". In VHDL, it can be done as follows:

```
x<=(x'length-1=>'1',others=>'0');
```

What will be the closest Verilog/SV equivalent ?

Comment: the VHDL one won't do precisely what you're asking either, unless the LSB is numbered 1 (not 0). You probably meant `x'left-1=>'1'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another method:

```
x <= {2'b01, {width_x-2{1'b0}}};
```

Or you can use bit shifting if width_x is relatively small:

```
x <= 1 << (width_x - 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need these 2 lines:
`x = 0; // to set all bits to 0` 
`x[width_x - 2] = 1'b1; // to set 2nd topmost bit to 1`

Below is more complete code.

```
module aa;
    parameter width_x = 14;
    
    logic [width_x-1:0] x;
    
    initial begin
        $display("x = %b", x);
        #10 x = 0;
        $display("x = %b", x);
        #10 x[width_x - 2] = 1'b1; 
        $display("x = %b", x);
        $finish;
    end
    endmodule
```